# Removing borders from a jQuery tab

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-tabs, squarespace

I am trying to create a minimalist tab on a client. What I wish to do is remove all of the borders around the tab. For some reason, the border keeps showing up.

Here is a sample that I've placed on my site to show the problem.
Here is the link: http://www.suttonst.com/govt-dev/

This is my CSS code:

```css
.ui-tabs { 
    background: transparent; 
    border: none; 
} 
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel { 
    background: transparent; 
    border: none; 
    font-family: "Georgia";
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #777777 
} 
.ui-tabs .ui-widget-content { 
    border: none;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-widget-header { 
    background: transparent; 
    border: none; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #006b54; 
    -moz-border-radius: 0px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px; 
    border-radius: 0px;
    font-family: "Varela Round";
    text-transform: uppercase;
} 
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav .ui-state-default { 
    background: transparent; 
    border: none; 
} 
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav .ui-state-active { 
   background: transparent    url(http://static.squarespace.com/static/51c0eec0e4b0c90d8d52ac7c/t/528ffa03e4b023ca755e496d/1385167363225/uiTabsArrowLogoEmeraldGreen.png) no-repeat bottom center; 
    border: none; 
} 
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav .ui-state-default a { 
    color: #006b54; 
} 
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav .ui-state-active a { 
    color: #cc6a30; 
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Please help.

Comment: you want to remove content border around?

Answer (score 3):

Remove the border from `ui-widget-content`, you were close with you third attempt but no space:

```css
.ui-tabs.ui-widget-content {
    border: none;
}
```

or use `#tabs` if you want to be very specific

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) problem try

```css
#tabs {
    border: none;
}
```

or

```css
.tabs.ui-corner-all{
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding with this line,

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li {
 border:none;
}
```

it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```css
.ui-corner-all {
    border: 0;
}
```